# How do i sort by users with profile pictures at the top?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, image

So i'm filling in for our developer at the moment (be for-warned i'm a beginner) but I"m trying to simply sort my search results by profiles that have a profile picture included (i.e, i don't want blank profile pictures to show up at the top of the results...they should all be at the end of the results)...Note that there are a couple user types which is why there is so much code...

I'm pretty sure where i'm going wrong is the 2 lines...

ORDER BY $order u.picture ISNULL DESC"; (which relates to ordering by profile pictures).  Would really appreciate any and all help...thx!

The code is as follows:

```
if ($user_type == 1) {
        $sql = "SELECT a.*, u.*,
                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) FROM LF_usertype_A WHERE usertype_BId = u.userId AND status = 1) as i_cnt,
                (SELECT COUNT(productId) FROM LF_products WHERE userId = u.userId AND status = 1) as product_cnt,
                (SELECT COUNT(transactionId)
                    FROM LF_Transactions
                    WHERE usertypeBId = u.userId
                        AND (status = 1 OR status = 2)
                        AND type = 9
                        AND userId != usertypeBId
                        AND userId != usertypeAId) AS cnt
                FROM LF_Users u
                JOIN LF_products a ON a.userId = u.userId
                LEFT JOIN LF_Transactions t ON t.productId = a.productId
                WHERE a.status = 1
                    AND u.status = 1
                    AND u.userType = :ut $where
                GROUP BY u.userID
                ORDER BY $order u.name DESC LIMIT 200";
    } elseif ($filter != "recent" && $user_type == 2) {
        $sql = "SELECT u.*,
                (SELECT COUNT(a.productId) FROM LF_usertypeA a INNER JOIN LF_products ON a.productId = m.productId INNER JOIN LF_Users uu ON uu.userId = a.usertypeAId WHERE a.userId = u.userId AND uu.status = 1 AND a.status = 1 AND m.status = 1) as product_cnt,
                (SELECT COUNT(transactionId)
                    FROM LF_Transactions
                    WHERE usertypeBId = u.userId
                        AND (status = 1 OR status = 2)
                        AND type = 9
                        AND userId != usertypeAId
                        AND userId != usertypeBId) AS cnt
                FROM LF_Users u
                LEFT JOIN LF_Transactions t ON t.usertypeBId = u.userId
                WHERE u.status = 1
                    AND u.userId != 1
                    AND u.userType = :ut $where
                GROUP BY u.userID
                ORDER BY $order u.name DESC LIMIT 200
                ORDER BY $order u.picture ISNULL DESC";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT u.*,
                (SELECT COUNT(a.productId) FROM LF_usertype_A a INNER JOIN LF_products m ON a.productId = m.productId INNER JOIN LF_Users uu ON uu.userId = a.usertypeAId WHERE a.userId = u.userId AND uu.status = 1 AND a.status = 1 AND m.status = 1) as product_cnt,
                (SELECT COUNT(transactionId)
                    FROM LF_Transactions
                    WHERE usertypeBId = u.userId
                        AND (status = 1 OR status = 2)
                        AND type = 9
                        AND userId != usertypeAId
                        AND userId != usertypeBId) AS cnt
                FROM LF_Users u
                WHERE u.status = 1
                AND u.userId != 1
                AND u.userType = :ut $where
                GROUP BY u.userID
                ORDER BY $order u.name DESC LIMIT 200
        ORDER BY $order u.picture ISNULL DESC";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to put the `isnull` condition before your regular sort order if you want it to take precedence:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(u.picture), $order
```

Comment: Thanks jeroen, can you give me an idea of where that would be in the code...i'm tyring ORDER BY ISNULL(u.picture), $order u.name DESC LIMIT 200.  Is that anywhere close?  I assume it still comes in after the 'GROUP BY' line, correct? thx!

Comment: @BennyB You have different sql statements and some of them seem to have multiple `ORDER BY` clauses. You can only have one `ORDER BY` clause in your sql statement and wherever you want the ones with images first, you have to start with `ISNULL(u.picture)`.

Comment: gotcha so the duplicate ORDER BY clauses are the issue.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @BennyB `$order u.name` seems wrong, unless `$order` ends with a comma.